# Variable in WinSCP script

Tags: windows, command-line, script, sftp, winscp

I'm asked to automate some SFTP download processes via WinSCP. I'm not familiar with WinSCP scripting.

ftprun.cmd:

```
C:\Program Files\WinSCP\winscp.com" /script=D:\testsftp\ftpscript.txt
```

ftpscript.txt:

```
option batch continue
option confirm off
open MRMRSA@sftp.merimen.com
set mydate=%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%
cd /cygdrive/h/ftproot/PROD/MRMRSA/eMotor/
lcd D:\testsftp
mkdir %mydate%
exit
```

When I run the script, system shows

> Unknown command 'set'.

Have been searching high and low to solve this but no luck.

Answer (score 4):

There's indeed no `set` command in WinSCP.

The [`set` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set_1), with syntax you are using, is a Windows command.

As such, you need to execute it from a Windows batch file, such as yours `ftprun.cmd`.

[WinSCP can resolve Windows environment variables](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#syntax) in its script:

So all you actually need to do is to move the `set` line to the `ftprun.cmd`, before the call to `winscp.com`:

```
set mydate=%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%
"C:\Program Files\WinSCP\winscp.com" /script=D:\testsftp\ftpscript.txt
```

---

Anyway, note that your `date` magic is locale-specific, so make sure that every machine, where you use the script, use the same locale (language) as the machine you develop/test this on. For example with my Czech locale, the `mydate` resolves to nonsense  `06.12čt`, because the `date` is `čt 12. 06. 2014`.

Better solution, is to use the WinSCP [`%TIMESTAMP%` syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp):

```
mkdir %TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%
```